# Creating a border that is part dashed and part solid line

Tags: java, swing, border

im creating a table, and in it there is one section that has all the cells where the top border is a solid line, but the bottom and right are dashed. I figured out how to individually make it not draw one side of the border, so I thought I could just combine a dashed and solid line border that are empty where the other needs to draw. Instead it just draws both on the top line. Here is my code:

```
Border empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, -1, -1, -1);
Border dashed = BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.BLUE, 5, 5);
Border empty2 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(-1, -1, -1, 0);
Border line = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
Border compound1 = new CompoundBorder(empty, line);
Border compound2= new CompoundBorder(empty2,dashed);
Border compound = new CompoundBorder(compound1,compound2);
```

Here is my full Code if you want to run it to see what im talking about:

```
* Class to create the specified table
 * @author CGordo01
 *
 */
public class WordDocumentTable extends JPanel{
    Font f;
    // Holds all the label, is used for resizing
    ArrayList<JLabel> allLabels= new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    /**
     * Creates the table
     */
    public WordDocumentTable(){

        // Sets the layout to a gridBagLayout
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        //Adds a component listener
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            /**
             * If the component is resized makes the text fit the dimensions
             */
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                // Boolean used to see if the text width fits the component.
                Boolean fits= false;

                // value used to divide the components height by.
                double divider = 16;

                // Makes the font size scale according to the width and height.
                while(fits == false){
                    f= f.deriveFont((float) (e.getComponent().getHeight()/divider));
                    for (int i = 0; i<allLabels.size();i++){
                        allLabels.get(i).setFont(f);
                        //System.out.println(divider);
                        if(allLabels.get(i).getGraphics().getFontMetrics().stringWidth(allLabels.get(i).getText())>allLabels.get(i).getWidth()){
                            fits = false;
                            divider++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            fits = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        makeLeftCells();

        makeMidCells();

        makeLongCells();

        makeTopCells();

    }
    /**
     * Creates the cells that are in between widths of the other cells
     */
    private void makeMidCells() {
        GridBagConstraints midCells = new GridBagConstraints();
        midCells.fill= GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        midCells.weightx=1;
        midCells.weighty=1;
        midCells.gridwidth=4;
        midCells.gridy=9;
        midCells.gridx=1;

        JLabel b = new JLabel();
        b.setText(".Batch Total    " + "    985124  " + "      Patches ");
        b.setName("Previous Batch Total");
        b.setBackground(Color.white);
        b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        b.setOpaque(true);
        b.setFont(f);
        this.add(b,midCells);

        midCells.gridx=5;
        JLabel b2 = new JLabel();
        b2.setText(".Shift Total    " + "    985124  " + "      Patches ");
        b2.setName("Previous Shift Total");
        b2.setBackground(Color.white);
        b2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        b2.setOpaque(true);
        b2.setFont(f);
        this.add(b2,midCells);

        midCells.gridy=12;
        midCells.gridx=1;

        JLabel c = new JLabel();
        c.setText(".Batch Total    " + "    985124  " + "      Patches ");
        c.setName("Batch Total");
        c.setBackground(Color.white);
        c.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        c.setOpaque(true);
        c.setFont(f);
        this.add(c,midCells);

        midCells.gridx=5;
        JLabel c2 = new JLabel();
        c2.setText(".Shift Total    " + "    985124  " + "      Patches ");
        c2.setName("Shift Total");
        c2.setBackground(Color.white);
        c2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        c2.setOpaque(true);
        c2.setFont(f);
        this.add(c2,midCells);

        allLabels.add(b);
        allLabels.add(b2);
        allLabels.add(c);
        allLabels.add(c2);
    }

        /**
         * Creates the cells which span much of the grid
         */
        private void makeLongCells() {
            GridBagConstraints longCells = new GridBagConstraints();
        longCells.fill= GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        longCells.weightx=1;
        longCells.weighty=1;
        longCells.gridwidth=8;
        longCells.gridx=1;
        longCells.gridy=7;

        JLabel b = new JLabel();
        b.setText("Finish the Batch");
        b.setName("Previous Shift Goal");
        b.setBackground(Color.white);
        b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        b.setOpaque(true);
        b.setFont(f);
        this.add(b,longCells);

        longCells.gridy=8;

        JLabel c = new JLabel();
        c.setText("<html><p> blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p></html>");
        c.setName("Previous Shift Notes");
        c.setBackground(Color.white);
        c.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        c.setOpaque(true);
        c.setFont(f);
        this.add(c,longCells);

        longCells.gridy=10;

        JLabel d = new JLabel();
        d.setText("Shift Goal");
        d.setName("Shift Goal");
        d.setBackground(Color.white);
        d.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        d.setOpaque(true);
        d.setFont(f);
        this.add(d,longCells);

        longCells.gridy=11;

        JLabel e = new JLabel();
        e.setText("Shift Notes");
        e.setName("Shift Goal");
        e.setBackground(Color.white);
        e.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        e.setOpaque(true);
        e.setFont(f);
        this.add(e,longCells);

        longCells.gridy=13;

        JLabel f2 = new JLabel();
        f2.setText("");
        f2.setName("WO Schedule Note");
        f2.setBackground(Color.white);
        f2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        f2.setOpaque(true);
        f2.setFont(f);
        this.add(f2,longCells);

        longCells.gridy=14;

        JLabel g = new JLabel();
        g.setText("");
        g.setName("Supervisor");
        g.setBackground(Color.white);
        g.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        g.setOpaque(true);
        g.setFont(f);
        this.add(g,longCells);

        allLabels.add(b);
        allLabels.add(c);
        allLabels.add(d);
        allLabels.add(e);
        allLabels.add(f2);
        allLabels.add(g);

    }
    /**
     * Creates a 8x7 grid of small cells 
     */
    private void makeTopCells() {
        GridBagConstraints topCells = new GridBagConstraints();
        topCells.fill= GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        topCells.weighty=1;
        topCells.weightx=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            topCells.gridx=i+1;
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                topCells.gridy=j;
                JLabel b = new JLabel();
                b.setText("" + i + j);
                b.setName("" + i + j);
                b.setOpaque(true);
                b.setFont(f);
                if(j==0){
                    b.setBackground(new Color(242,242,242));
                }
                else{
                    b.setBackground(Color.white);
                }
                if (j==0){
                    b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
                }
                else{
                    Border empty = null;
                    Border compound = null;
                    Border dashed = BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.BLUE, 5, 5);
                    if(j==1){
                    empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(-1, 0, -1, -1);
                    }
                    else{
                        empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, -1, -1);
                    }
                    if(j!=4){
                    compound = new CompoundBorder(empty, dashed);
                    }
                    else{
                        empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, -1, -1, -1);
                        Border empty2 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(-1, -1, -1, 0);
                        Border line = new LineBorder(Color.black);
                        Border compound1 = new CompoundBorder(empty, line);
                        Border compound2= new CompoundBorder(empty2,dashed);
                        compound = new CompoundBorder(compound1,compound2);

                    }
                    b.setBorder(compound);
                }

                allLabels.add(b);
                this.add(b,topCells);
            }
        }

    }

    private void makeLeftCells() {
        GridBagConstraints leftCells = new GridBagConstraints();

        leftCells.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        leftCells.gridx = 0;
        leftCells.gridy = 0;
        leftCells.weightx=2;
        leftCells.weighty=1;

        JLabel titleBlock = new JLabel();
        titleBlock.setOpaque(true);
        titleBlock.setText("Delta Hydrogel A");
        titleBlock.setForeground(Color.white);
        titleBlock.setBackground(new Color(79,129,189));
        titleBlock.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        titleBlock.setFont(f);

        this.add(titleBlock, leftCells);

        leftCells.gridy = 1;
        leftCells.gridheight=3;

        JLabel tallBlock1 = new JLabel();
        tallBlock1.setOpaque(true);
        tallBlock1.setText(".Day Shift");
        tallBlock1.setForeground(Color.black);
        tallBlock1.setBackground(new Color(242,242,242));
        tallBlock1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        tallBlock1.setFont(f);
        this.add(tallBlock1, leftCells);



        JLabel tallBlock2 = new JLabel();
        tallBlock2.setOpaque(true);
        tallBlock2.setText(".Night Shift");
        tallBlock2.setForeground(Color.black);
        tallBlock2.setBackground(new Color(242,242,242));
        tallBlock2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        tallBlock2.setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 4;

        this.add(tallBlock2, leftCells);

        JLabel shortBlock1 = new JLabel();
        shortBlock1.setOpaque(true);
        shortBlock1.setText(".Previous Shift Goal");
        shortBlock1.setForeground(Color.black);
        shortBlock1.setBackground(new Color(242,242,242));
        shortBlock1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        shortBlock1.setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 7;
        leftCells.gridheight=1;

        this.add(shortBlock1, leftCells);

        JLabel shortBlockTall = new JLabel();
        shortBlockTall.setOpaque(true);
        shortBlockTall.setText(".Previous Shift Notes");
        shortBlockTall.setForeground(Color.black);
        shortBlockTall.setBackground(new Color(242,242,242));
        shortBlockTall.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        shortBlockTall.setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 8;
        leftCells.ipady=50;

        this.add(shortBlockTall, leftCells);

        JLabel shortBlock2 = new JLabel();
        shortBlock2.setOpaque(true);
        shortBlock2.setText(".Previous Shift Output");
        shortBlock2.setForeground(Color.black);
        shortBlock2.setBackground(new Color(242,242,242));
        shortBlock2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        shortBlock2.setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 9;
        leftCells.ipady=0;


        this.add(shortBlock2, leftCells);

        JLabel shortBlock3 = new JLabel();
        shortBlock3.setOpaque(true);
        shortBlock3.setText(".Shift Goals");
        shortBlock3.setForeground(Color.black);
        shortBlock3.setBackground(new Color(184,204,228));
        shortBlock3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        shortBlock3.setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 10;
        leftCells.ipady=0;


        this.add(shortBlock3, leftCells);


        JLabel shortBlock4 = new JLabel();
        shortBlock4.setOpaque(true);
        shortBlock4.setText(".Shift Notes");
        shortBlock4.setForeground(Color.black);
        shortBlock4.setBackground(new Color(184,204,228));
        shortBlock4.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        shortBlock4.setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 11;
        leftCells.ipady=0;


        this.add(shortBlock4, leftCells);

        JLabel shortBlock5 = new JLabel();
        shortBlock5.setOpaque(true);
        shortBlock5.setText(".Output");
        shortBlock5.setForeground(Color.black);
        shortBlock5.setBackground(new Color(184,204,228));
        shortBlock5.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        shortBlock5.setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 12;


        this.add(shortBlock5, leftCells);

        JLabel shortBlock6 = new JLabel();
        shortBlock6.setOpaque(true);
        shortBlock6.setText(".WO Schedule Note");
        shortBlock6.setForeground(Color.black);
        shortBlock6.setBackground(new Color(184,204,228));
        shortBlock6.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        shortBlock6 .setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 13;

        this.add(shortBlock6, leftCells);

        JLabel shortBlock7 = new JLabel();
        shortBlock7.setOpaque(true);
        shortBlock7.setText(".Supervisor");
        shortBlock7.setForeground(Color.black);
        shortBlock7.setBackground(new Color(184,204,228));
        shortBlock7.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        shortBlock7.setFont(f);
        leftCells.gridy = 14;

        this.add(shortBlock7, leftCells);

        allLabels.add(titleBlock);
        allLabels.add(tallBlock1);
        allLabels.add(tallBlock2);
        allLabels.add(shortBlock1);
        allLabels.add(shortBlockTall);
        allLabels.add(shortBlock2);
        allLabels.add(shortBlock3);
        allLabels.add(shortBlock4);
        allLabels.add(shortBlock5);
        allLabels.add(shortBlock6);
        allLabels.add(shortBlock7);



    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame J = new JFrame();
        J.setSize(1600,900);
        J.setVisible(true);


        WordDocumentTable wdc= new WordDocumentTable();

        J.setContentPane(wdc);
        J.setVisible(true);
        J.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Instead it just draws both on the top line.` I see a solid top line and a dashed right line when I run your code. Post a proper [Runnable Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hey, I posted my complete code for the table. I know I could of shortened it greatly but it runs in that example and hopefully you can see what I'm going for, and the problem

Comment: Don't have time to look at all that code. `I know I could of shortened it greatly but it runs in that example` - so you have proved the code works. Now you need to determine what is different between the shortened version and the full version. Start by adding in small amounts of code to the short version and test until it breaks. Then when it breaks you know what has changed and you can concentrate your debugging efforts there.

Comment: By the way you don't need to create new Borders for every component. Borders can be shared. So create one of each different type of Border that you need. Then just set the appropriate Border for each component. That might help simply the code and find your problem.

Comment: If you set the proper Border than the Border should be painted. If you don't see the proper Border then I would guess your logic to assign the Border is incorrect. Since I don't know your intended logic I can't help. Add  a debug statement into the else statement that creates your compound border to see if the code is executing as you expect.

Comment: I think I worded that badly. When I said "I know I could of shortened it greatly but it runs in that example". By that example I mean the complete code I posted. And the compound border when split(lets say i set compound1 as the compound border) works how expected.

Comment: Would sharing borders be more efficient?

Comment: Sharing Borders creates fewer components. Instead of creating 56 Borders you create one. It won't affect painting.

Answer (score 0):

Well Im not sure I understand it but I made it work. I changed the first parameter in the empty border that was for the dash line to -2. My reasoning was -1 doesnt work, lets try -2.

```
Border empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, -1, -1, -1);
Border dashed = BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.BLUE, 5, 5);
Border empty2 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(-2, -1, -1, 0);
Border line = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
Border compound1 = new CompoundBorder(empty, line);
Border compound2= new CompoundBorder(empty2,dashed);
Border compound = new CompoundBorder(compound1,compound2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to implement your own Border.

Comment: (-1), I already stated the code works for me and the OP already stated it works for him when he created a demo program, so the problem is not the Border.

Comment: Well, I posted my suggestion *before* OP stated that it works. Moreover even if it works, it does not means it is correct. EmptyBorder with negative insets has not much sense for me.